# Facebook Like button is not showing my website but the hosting company

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I have added a Facebook like button to my website which is nichesbc.com, the button is located on my contact page, the button works fine but when you click the like button it is not my website that will show in someones timeline but the hosting company that is hosting my site in this case bluehost. I don't know what is wrong or how I can fix it, any advice?

Comment: Can you check your server error log?  I think you are liking a 404 error page - possibly due to your channel file https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#channel

Comment: I just check my error logs and it says there is too many redirects. I added my channel file and it is still doing the same thing. Any other ideas what it could be. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've run it through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nichesbc.com%2F and it seems to have updated and be working now.